# how to retrieve row names based on row number in R?

Tags: r

For example, I have a row index vector i=(2,1,8), how to retrieve their corresponding row names from a data.frame?  Can't figure out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

well, if your data.frame is named `dd`, then

```
rownames(dd)
```

returns the row names, so

```
rownames(dd)[i]
```

will return the row names for rows 2,1 and 8.

Comment: This works. Then How to subset a data.frame based on column names, if the column names are in a vector colVector?

Comment: well, first of all, comments are not a good place to ask new, different questions. It's generally better to open a new question on the site. But if you have a vector of column names called `cn` and you want to select just those columns from your data.frame named `dd`, then `dd[, cn]` would work.